Blob download saves as .bin with a random filename instead of .webm
I'm developing a Tampermonkey userscript to capture audio from a webpage using the MediaRecorder API. The script successfully records audio and creates a Blob with the MIME type audio/webm;codecs=opus. However, when I attempt to download the generated audio file, it's saved with a .bin extension and a random 9-digit filename (e.g. 1298453815.bin) instead of the intended recording.webm.
This is the relevant code snippet.
// Media recorder handling above
const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/webm;codecs=opus' });
const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);

const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = audioUrl;
link.download = 'recording.webm';
link.click();

I've tried various methods to enforce the correct filename and extension, including explicitly setting the download attribute of the anchor tag and setting the type attribute. Trying GM_download on blob URL, using FileReader to convert the blob to a data URL. I've also tested with simple text files created from blobs, and the issue persists. I also inspected the network tab and it shows that the request headers are set with the correct MIME types.
Crucially, I know this is possible and not a browser limitation due to the fact that this site https://editor.audio/ uses blobs for export and the "Save as" window appears with the correct filename and extension.
Could anyone clarify what I'm missing? Is there a proper way to ensure that the downloaded file has the correct filename and extension when using blobs in a Tampermonkey userscript? I'm particularly interested in understanding why the download attribute and GM_download are not working as expected in this context, and how the website I linked manages to achieve the desired behavior.

What browser are you using? have you tried an isolated test? eg: new Blob([JSON.stringify({foo: "Hello World"})], {type: "application/json"});

@GTK I'm using Xbrowser The isolated test does work, it is saving with a .json extension.

it could be that browser, firefox for android supports add-ons, you can install tampermonkey and test it.

It was the browser. I found a workaround as audio/mp3 is supported, I'm doing the mp3 conversion. Thank you for your time!

glad you figured it out! if you can post an answer detailing the cause/solution, that would be very helpful for other people in the future.
